# How do I see WebSocket HTTP upgrade response in Chrome Dev tools?

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I have a WebSocket server that responds with a HTTP response to the initial HTTP upgrade request.

When the WebSocket is working correctly this is fine.

But when an error is returned to the upgrade request as a HTTP JSON response (not a WebSocket frame) Chrome dev tools does not show it and just fails on the `WebSocket` constructor.

Charles proxy shows me the HTTP response text - so it is there.

[image]

How can I see the HTTP response in Chrome dev tools?